# TemplatedParent - A clarification

Tags: .net, wpf

Here's the Tree:

- MyControl : BOUND(IContentMenuItem)

  - ControlTemplate

    - ContentPresenter : BOUND(Header, HeaderTemplate, HeaderTemplateSelector)

      - DataTemplate (For Header)

        - Label

I Want to bind The Label @ the end of that tree to a property on the DataContext of `MyControl`

I can use **FindAncestor** to get the `MyControl` (Obviously) but how do I bind to it's DataContext (of type `IContentMenuItem`)

---

**Now for the Templated Parent Question**

Will Binding to the `TemplatedParent` inside the DataTemplate in effect bind to The `ContentPresenter`, The `ControlTemplate`, or The `MyControl` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer to the TemplatedParent question is the `ContentPresenter` -- it is whatever the template is being applied to.

If you can get `MyControl` using `FindAncestor`, then you can bind to properties of the DataContext like this:

```
<Label Content="{Binding DataContext.MyProperty, RelativeSource=…}" />
```

You can also just set an `x:Name` for `MyControl` and then the binding looks like:

```
<Label Content="{Binding DataContext.MyProperty, ElementName=myControl}" />
```